# try/catch not working inside UnhandledException handler

Tags: c#, exception, unhandled-exception

I've got a weird symptom in an application, where try/catches inside the handler for UnhandledExceptions don't work: (that is a breakpoint inside the `catch` does not get hit, even if the breakpoint inside the `try` does).

Obviously searching for 'exception unhandled inside UnhandledException' is not working very well for me.

I've tried doing a mini proof-of-concept, and unfortunately that one works.

So while I'm trying to track down the root of the problem, if anyone here has any ideas where to look I'd be greatful.

*(We recently changed from XP to Windows7, and .Net 4.5 from 4.0 - I'm pretty certain that previously this worked).*

**EDIT**: Looks like it's provoked by a call down to a (managed) C++ library which is throwing a `System.AccessViolationException`. Strangely, if I replace the call with a `throw new AccessViolationException`, it does do what I want...

Comment: Try pushing exceptions in one `AggregateException` and rethrow it - that is common practice in .NET

Comment: i think we can't handle Unhandeled exception and have to exit application in finally.

Comment: So you are doing some work inside your UnhandledException which in turn is throwing an exception which you want to catch?

Comment: Does your working proof of concept app include `throw new AccessViolationException` or does it do something to cause a _real_ exception of this type? I wouldn't trust the 'working' behaviour if this exception was faked - see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote, "We recently changed ... .Net 4.5 from 4.0 - I'm pretty certain that previously this worked." but the following seems worth adding, because *pretty sure* really means *not certain* :-)

I read somewhere that `AccessViolationException` cannot occur in managed code, but may be trapped by the runtime for unmanaged code. Maybe the C++ library calls into unmanaged code?

In .NET 4+ the process will terminate after `AccessViolationException`. Your exception handler will be ignored. This is among a group of exception types considered unrecoverable: [Corrupted State Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419661.aspx). In .NET 4+ you will need to customise the app config to override this behaviour.

Comment: The green sharp thing is yours, sir. You are right on both counts: the [`legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) 'fixes' this, and throwing AccessViolationException apparently does nothing of the sort. Many thanks indeed.

Comment: According to [this](http://antipatterns.blogspot.ch/2012/07/unhandled-exception-after-moving-to-net.html) another alternative is to add the `[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]` attribute on the Handler.

Comment: @Benjol - Further to _I read somewhere ..._ in my answer above, [Corrupted State Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419661.aspx) states that, "an access violation received from Windows will be marked as a corrupted state exception (CSE), but one raised in user code by writing throw new System.AccessViolation­Exception will not be marked as a CSE."

Comment: @Benjol - Have you been able to use `[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]` successfully? I ask because a year ago when I tried this it made no difference. I must have missed something but ended up deciding not to, because _(a)_ the `AccessViolationException` went away (it was caused by a bug in a 3rd party DLL that was fixed), and _(b)_ we decided to apply the advice in the MSDN article: it was too hard to design recovery code for this error.

Comment: well it *seems* to have worked. I've also asked for the underlying dll to be fixed, but in this case I didn't really care about 'recovering' per se, just failing gracefully (i.e. logging and not showing the default Windows 'phone home' dialogue)

Comment: @Benjol - you can prove it works by setting a breakpoint in the exception handler and if the debugger breaks at that point, you've proved it.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that you try to catch `System.AccessViolationException` and not native Access Violation error.

When you do `throw new AccessViolationException` it throws `System.AccAccessViolationException`.
If library that you calls is native it can throw native Access Violation error, but .NET `catch` block normally can catch only managed exceptions.

Comment: Good idea, doesn't *seem* to be that in this case though.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
i think we can't handle Unhandeled exception and have to exit application in finally.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx